# dask execution gets stuck in LocalCluster

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using an `EC2` VM with `16 cores` and `64GB ram`. Wrote a `Dask` program that applies a filter on a dataframe and does a `concat` with another one and then writes the data back to disk. If I run it in `LocalCluster` mode by calling simply `client = Client()`, the execution gets stuck at some point after writing some data. During this period, the `CPU` utilisation is very very low and I can easily understand that nothing is getting executed. Also size of the part files stops increasing at this point. This goes on forever. But If I execute it without creating `LocalCluster`, it runs very slowly (low `CPU` utilisation) and finishes up the program. Trying to understand how I can fix this.

Note: Nobody else is using the VM and the data size ranges from 3GB to 25GB.

Dask version: 2.15.0 & 2.17.2

Comment: Do you mind to create a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not enough information in your question to provide a helpful answer.  There are many things that could be going on.

In this situation we recommend watching the Dask dashboard, which can give you much more information about what is going on.  Hopefully that can help you identify your issue.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html

Comment: Thanks @MRocklin. Unfortunately the dashboard is not accessible as all ports except `22` (ssh) are closed in the VM due to security reasons. But it seems to be an issue related to bad data as I was facing this only for couple of files. Rest of them are getting processed successfully.

Comment: In that case I recommend using SSH Port forwarding to get access to the dashboard